# Substring of an element in a set

Tags: c++, set, substring

Is there a way to find and replace subset of a char*/string in a set?

Example:

```
std::set<char*> myset; 
myset.insert("catt");
myset.insert("world");
myset.insert("hello");

it = myset.subsetfind("tt"); 
myset.replace(it, "t");
```

Comment: For associative containers you should not use a pointer as the key, as then it will be ***pointer*** that is the key and not the data it points to. If you want the key to be a string, then you should use `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three reasons why this won't work.

1. `std::set` provides only the means to search the set for a value that compares equally to the value being searched for, and not to a value that matches some arbitrary portion of the value.
2. The shown program is undefined behavior. A string literal, such as "hello" is a `const char *`, and not a `char *`. No self-respecting C++ compiler will allow you to insert a `const char *` into a container of `char *`s. And you can't modify `const` values, by definition, anyway.
3. Values in `std::set` cannot be modified. To effect the modification of an existing value in a set, it must be `erase`()d, then the new value `insert`()ed.

`std::set` is simply not the right container for the goals you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Unfortunately ICC, GCC and Clang all compile with only GCC and Clang issuing a warning.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't (or at least shouldn't) modify the key while it's in the set. Doing so could change the relative order of the elements, in which case the modification would render the set invalid.

You need to start with a set of things you can modify. Then you need to search for the item, remove it from the set, modify it, then re-insert the result back into the set.

```
std::set<std::string> myset {"catt", "world", "hello"};
auto pos = std::find_if(myset.begin(), myset.end(), [](auto const &s) { return s.find("tt");};

if (pos != myset.end()) {
    auto temp = *pos;
    myset.remove(pos);
    auto p= temp.find("tt");
    temp.replace(p, 2, "t");
    myset.insert(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify elements within a set.

You can find strings that contain the substring using `std::find_if`. Once you find matching elements, you can remove each from the set and add a modified copy of the string, with the substring replaced with something else.

PS. Remember that you cannot modify string literals. You will need to allocate some memory for the strings.

PPS. Implicit conversion of string literal to `char*` has been deprecated since C++ was standardized, and since C++11 such conversion is ill-formed.

PPPS. The default comparator will not be correct when you use pointers as the element type. I recommend you to use `std::string` instead. (A `strcmp` based comparator approach would also be possible, although much more prone to memory bugs).

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use `std::find_if` with a predicate function/functor/lambda that searches for the substring you want.